# Is NinePatchDrawable+setColorFilter HW Accelerated in Honeycomb?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-3.0-honeycomb, hardware-acceleration

I'm building compound controls (UI controls that consist of multiple standard UI controls) and I need HW acceleration (Honeycomb only app).

The typical control will look like this:

ViewGroup (some layout subclass) with a NinePatchDrawable background + setColorFilter on the background drawable.

Inside that, one or more Views with a NinePatchDrawable background + setColorFilter on the background drawable.

I'll build up my UI from compound controls like this.

Will this hierarchy be hardware accelerated?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is supported by the hw accelerated pipeline.